# Why don't all teachers use clickers?

Tags: interactive-teaching, large-lecture

As a school project we've developed a web based tool (similar to a clicker) which helps the teacher understand how large proportion of their students actually understand what she/he says. Now we've been approached by our school's business incubator who thinks we should commercialize the idea.

What makes our solution unique right now is our focus on extreme simplicity both for teachers and students, but there are many similar ideas on the market. That makes me wonder why they haven't succeeded in making clickers omnipresent. Only a small percentage of lecturers use these tools despite claims from their manufacturers that they improve learning dramatically.

Why doesn't every teacher use a clicker or similar tool? Is it just tradition or are there practical issues to using them that discourage most teachers?

Comment: Do you want us to each give our individual reasons for not using them? The way your question is worded, I think that is what you will get.

Comment: What is a "clicker"?

Comment: @Chris I would like to know as many reasons as possible or the reason that most lecturers feel is most relevant. When thinking about commercializing our idea, I looked at other alternative technologies and started wondering why they hadn't succeeded as well.

Comment: @mbork a clicker is a system of small devices handed out to each student to allow them to answer questions during class. It allows for a more interactive lecture. Here's one example [link](http://www1.iclicker.com/audience-response-system). Our system is similar, but only focuses on the question we felt was most relevant: "do you understand?". It's also easier, quicker and cheaper to set up but I don't even know if this is an issue for lecturers.

Comment: @JohanWikström: I see.  What a strange idea.  Why not just *ask* the students in a "traditional" way?  Frankly, I can't see much point in using such devices, at least in the context of teaching.  (Game shows, that's another story;).)  And BTW: I've *never* heard of anything like that, so I'd suggest explaining it in the question.

Comment: @mbork the idea is that you can see what students participate in questions without going around the class, allow students to answer without peer pressure, etc. (which is not to say that I disagree with you). Some lecturers love them, some hate them, most are indifferent to them where I work.

Comment: @RobM yes but our tool focuses on giving the lecturer a **quick** overview on how much the students understand, **without interrupting the lecture**. In my experience, peer pressure is a much larger problem if the students are expected to stop the lecturer when they don't understand and this problem grows with the class size. Maybe this is not a problem in the US, but in Sweden most people feel uncomfortable stopping the lecture and proclaiming in front of 100+ peers that they don't understand.

Comment: @RobM: interesting.  I'm still not convinced (I even asked a question on clickers a minute ago).  I don't see the need to go around the class; at my university, most lectures are attended by at most two-digit number of students; in this case, a student can just ask a question aloud.  Also, I would argue that an important part of the role of the university is to teach students to be mature human beings, which means (among other things) some resilience against peer pressure.  Taking that pressure (artificially!) away from them means depriving them from an important kind of experience.

Comment: @mbork I for one totally agree with you. Not everyone feels that way, and of course for younger students the dynamic might be slightly different again.

Comment: And to be clear: I'm not against technology *per se*, and I use it (also when teaching).  But I guess it's important to have a backup plan in case electricity goes off.

Comment: @mbork, "most lectures are attended by at most two-digit number of students" So... 99 students per class? :) I kid, obviously, but your statement _could_ mean that.

Comment: @BrianS: yes, I *did* mean that.  In Poland, there are a few types of class: an "exercise class", with groups of at most ±30 students, a "lecture" with anything between 1 and, say, 150 students (these are not compulsory, and hence a low lower bound;)), and a few variations on these.  Nowadays, lectures with more than 100 students are very rare.  OTOH, I did give some "popular" lectures (mostly to high-schoolers) attended by something like 200 people.

Comment: I have a very low-tech clicker technology I use in all my classes. When a student doesn't understand something I say, they raise their hand and ask a question.

Comment: @mbork, 99 students seems like a rather large lecture hall to simply "ask a question aloud." If there were 20 students in the room, someone speaking out could be easily heard, identified, and answered. If there are 99 students in the room, someone speaking out might not even be noticed among the random noise generated by people shifting in their seats, typing notes on laptops, yawning, etc.

Comment: @BrianS: you're right, but see James S. Cook's comment above;).

Comment: Even if you substitute random outbursts of questions with hand-raising, it can be difficult to spot a raised hand in a large crowd like that until you pause to specifically take questions and start looking for those raised hands. :)

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I know for a fact that not everybody does that. Often the lecturer takes a giant perceptual leap and when the student has realized that he/she doesn't understand, the lecture has progressed so far that they don't even know what to ask.

Comment: @Brian Back in university days we used to knock on the table if we had questions then raise the hand. Although that seems to be more an Austrian thing - didn't see that behavior at all in the US. At least takes care of that problem quite well.

Comment: @JohanWikström that's why you take notes and make use of office hours as needed, or, in my case, send me an email. Perhaps also, there is a reason a leap is made in lecture. Perhaps to provoke thought at times. Clickers have a place, but, I'm quite certain it is not in junior and senior level math courses or more generally populations of less than 40.

Comment: I recently saw [a presentation](http://meetings.aps.org/Meeting/APR14/Session/R9.3) about a study claiming that clickers have a neutral to detrimental effect on learning in physics classes. I would imagine the same conclusion might hold in math, to some extent.

Comment: @mbork I agree that it is good to help students to be resilient to peer pressure, but putting up a barrier to mathematical understanding is not the same as teaching resilience to peer pressure.  Teaching is not just putting up obstacles for students to overcome, and if you really want to teach students to be confident in speaking in front of large groups of their peers do it in another class.  If you are supposed to be teaching math, that means using knowledge of your students' current understanding to help them to grow and deepen their understanding.  Clickers are a way to get that knowledge.

Comment: I think the answer to the question is in @mbork's first comment above.

Comment: Clickers were used in one of my physics classes.  About half the students like to choose an invalid option whenever available (that is, for an "A) True, B) False" question, they'd indicate C, D, or E).  He stopped using the clickers after about 4 lectures.  About 1/3rd of the rest of the class never bought them, and so couldn't participate anyway.

Comment: @DavidZ: Clickers are not the same thing as student-centered learning, a.k.a. interactive engagement (IE). There is solid research supporting IE in physics. See Hake, "Interactive Engagement Versus Traditional Methods: a Six-Thousand Student Survey of Mechanics Test Data for Introductory Physics Courses, Am. J. of Phys, 66 (1997) 64, plus a large body of later literature. The research shows that straight lecturing or other non-IE methods never seem to produce acceptable gains in conceptual understanding, while IE often does. One classic IE method is described in [...]

Comment: [...] Mazur, Peer Instruction: A User's Manual, 1996. It involves a low-tech polling technique (students hold up pieces of paper to vote), with follow-up discussion in groups, then a second round of polling to see if the right answer has driven out the wrong one. The follow-up discussion is what makes it IE.

Comment: @BenCrowell yes, I know. The presentation I saw was specifically about clickers, not IE.

Comment: This is another item the students have to keep track of, for use some two hours a week. Most will misplace it soon, leave it at home, ...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Every time I add a new technological object to my classroom, I increase the chances that my class does not happen that day.

Imagine if you could only make copies for your students in class in front of your students, but the copies came out very quickly. This would be extremely stressful, because when you brought a quiz to class, there would be a small chance that the copier would not work that day, and so your class would be compromised.

Clickers and all other technological advances in the classroom are thus (for me) automatically suspect since they make the class inherently less reliable.

Comment: I agree 100%. Standing in front of a bunch of people and teaching them something they don't already know right out of your head incorporates a certain element of 'magic'. Standing at the front of the class while a student fetches someone to help with an interactive whiteboard destroys that magic.

Comment: "Every time I add a new technological object to my classroom, I increase the chances that my class does not happen that day."

True, but this doesn't mean we shouldn't use technology if it makes sense and can improve student learning. If the payoff is greater than the risk, then it wouldn't make sense NOT to use technology.

Comment: I don't think clickers are very disruptive (as described above) and as such shouldn't impede you having your class without them like you do today.  The copier analogy is not a good one.

Comment: @DavidWilkins I'm standing by the copier analogy. A quiz that fails to be copied does not impede me having my class, but it removes an assessment from the syllabus and I will have to fix the grading of the course. Similarly a clicker that fails to work does not impede me from holding my class, but I will have to deal with the same grading issues due to missed attendance/participation points. RobertTalbert's point is a better counterargument -- that of course there is some risk but perhaps it is worth taking.

Comment: @ChrisCunningham My intent was not to completely disagree, I don't think clickers are a good alternative to raising one's hand, but I say that without having been involved with lectures consisting of over 80 students, unless you consider performance classes like band/orchestra, in which a clicker would be extremely disruptive and prohibitive.

Comment: Are the clickers being used for class grading? I thought they were just a class participation aide, in which case if they malfunctioned you could switch back to hand raising and proceed on. So I agree that the photocopier analogy is not a very good one since there's almost no chance a clicker failure will prevent your class from happening, as you say.

Comment: @JLRishe If you don't attach some small number of points to the use of the clickers, many students will choose not to spend the money, time, and effort required to participate in that part of the class. As a result, almost everyone assigns a small number of participation points to clicker usage. This is identical to the standard philosophy on quizzes -- students will not bother to do the quizzes unless they are worth some small number of points.

Answer (score 25):

Here's what I've found, based on my own clicker use for the last 5-6 years and by doing clicker workshops:

- **Cost**. Clickers (and their software BYOD variants) cost money and many profs don't want to ask students to buy Yet Another Item for class when textbooks are so expensive already. Also, many IT departments don't want the hassle of managing fleets of clickers.
- **Shelf life**. To make matters worse, there's often no standardization among clicker devices on the same campus, so one class will require [Turning Point RF](http://www.turningtechnologies.com/response-solutions/responsecard-rf) clickers and another will require a [Top Hat](http://tophat.com) license while another will require an iClicker. In this case students end up laying down serious amounts of money for essentially a unitasking device -- or rather, several of them, which will likely never see the light of day after the course is over.
- **Not having a sense of how best to use the things**. There are some amazing things you can do pedagogically with clickers, but many faculty don't see these or fail to think outside the lecture box. Or, the faculty know what can be done but it sounds time-consuming to convert lectures over to clicker-driven classes, so they bail. (Which is too bad since this is not entirely true.)

For me, having just spend a semester using a web-based BYOD type of clicker implementation, I'm not so sure I'm going to stick with it. The web-based tool I used had some neat features that physical clickers can't do, but I lost track of how many times someone's wifi connection would drop out in the middle of a lesson or something like that. Physical clicker devices *just work* IMO.

Comment: Just for reference, do you have a link to that web-based tool? It would be very helpful to us. So the main problem is that the web devices don't work all the time? That's interesting.

Comment: @JohanWikström: the most reliable technology is no technology, or simple one like paper & pencil, wooden stick acting as a pointer, chalk & blackboard etc.  With *any* electrical device there is at least one way something may go wrong (flat battery), and with *any* web/network-based device the number of ways something may go wrong is much larger.  (That said, I admit I like technology/gadgets etc. a lot;).)

Comment: @JohanWikström - It's Top Hat that I used this semester, but honestly I don't know how much of the issues that I had to do with Top Hat, or how much had to do with our sometimes-spotty network or with the students' devices. The wifi-based solutions to me are still an emerging technology despite the near-ubiquity of wifi itself.

Answer (score 16):

*Only a small percentage of lecturers use these tools despite claims from their manufacturers that they improve learning dramatically.*

Maybe people who actually use these tools have a different opinion on their effectiveness to that of people trying to sell these tools?

I'm a part of the network support team in a college, I don't deal directly with classroom support for things like this all that much but I talk to staff who do support it, and lecturers who are actually in the classrooms.

As Chris says, it's one more thing to go wrong - not just in the local sense of "batteries won't work" but for a web-based tool like you have (?) it's at the mercy of someone like me having a bad morning and blocking half the internet by accident (it can happen). It's something else that might get lost, stolen, or whatever. It's one more thing to set up.

These might sound like small issues but there is a wildly varying level of comfort and confidence in using IT technology in lecturers and for those who are not comfortable with technology, no matter how simple you make these things, they're still a trial to endure rather than a tool to help them.

And that's not even considering that some lecturers will be quite happy using alternative methods. Despite being an IT person myself and quite comfortable with using technology, if you're ever in a lecture room listening to me talk about something expect me to write on all the whiteboards many times over before expecting to see anything like a clicker appear.

Comment: Yes, it's a web based thing and I'm curious. Do you think that there is a level of simplicity that is so low that it wont feel like a trial? Is it mainly the time spent on technology that might not work or is it too many buttons/logins/apps etc that make people feel overwhelmed?

Comment: For someone who is worried about things going wrong, or lacks confidence in the equipment (or even might be perfectly confident but has a *lot* going on in a session), it's not the load of managing that one system, it's the load of managing that one system *on top of everything else* in the same way that it doesn't matter how light an easy a laptop is to carry in one hand if both your hands are already full anyway.

Comment: Haha, I guess I'm oldschool enough that I consider *white*boards (as opposed to *black*boards) already too much technology (chalk is much more reliable than whiteboard markers!).

Comment: "Maybe people who actually use these tools have a different opinion on their effectiveness to that of people trying to sell these tools?" +100 for that sentence.

Comment: And one more thing: "someone like me having a bad morning and blocking half the internet by accident (it can happen)." – now I understand why I couldn't use the web yesterday – it must have been RobM's fault...

Comment: It usually is @mbork :) - and Johan, I'm sure you're aware of this but it really does make little sense to base your marketing on what your competitors *claim* is happening, surely.

Comment: Yes, I was kind of hoping to learn something about the discrepancy between our competitors claims and reality ;)

Comment: In that case I hope we're helping. Keep in mind a large part of it is personal preference of the lecturer concerned (and for that matter, the class, with older students). There's no easy way of beating this into a simple answer imho.

Comment: I studied CS in university and some projector or the projection screen or laptop not working and holding up a lecture despite a room full of CS people certainly happened more than once. So yes I can't really argue with the argument here.

Answer (score 13):

As in other answers and comments: while in gigantic "classes" one might hope to either get meaningful responses, or do quick polling/quizzing via in-real-time responses, ... techno-glitches make it impossible to depend on these, in the first place.

The potential plus that feedback can be anonymous, allowing perhaps more sincere response than otherwise, would be a wonderful result to realize. However, in those huge-class scenarios, and given our contemporary academic culture, there is scant reason to believe that clicker responses are ... that.

The faux-benefits of anonymous response are misleading, I think. Instead, I've always implemented systems that allow me to learn everyone's name even in classes of up-to-150. Even if "kids" seem to desire a sort of anonymity, it seems to me that they *benefit* from belief that the instructor is aware of them as an individual, not as a stat on a clicker.

Reading facial expressions and body language gives me quite a lot of information. Techno-vulnerable yes-no stuff is not only limited and high-overhead, but too narrow a pipe for what I want to know about the people in the room.

(I'm not at all a technophobe, btw, having written a web browser in Perl, etc. But not a technophiliac, either. Trying to be a realist.)

Comment: +1 for the "classes". Nicely said.

Comment: `allowing perhaps more sincere response than otherwise` - Nah, not all of use cared.  We knew they were anonymous and not part of the grade, so (at least within my group of friends) we just hit the nearest button on the clicker.  And "E" usually wasn't an option.

Answer (score 12):

I've used clickers and helped other faculty with clickers for over 10 years. I'm at a very large, very research-oriented public university. Here are the reasons I've seen for why research faculty don't use clickers when they teach:

- They team-teach, which means all instructors have to agree to use
  them
- They teach only 5 weeks a year, and have to re-learn the technology each time. They get very frustrated with changes in software and hardware
- They have a low tolerance for student confusion with technology. Without an expert TA to do the grading and solve student problems, clickers are too much work.

Our teaching faculty (senate-level lecturers) all teach much more often and all use some sort of audience response device. This group is generally willing to try anything and can make anything work. The major difficulty with BYOD web-clickers is:

- The lecture hall wifi can't handle 440 students submitting at once
- Not every single student wants to bring a device to class. This is less of a problem as smartphones become nearly ubiquitous, but still.

Answer (score 8):

People have mentioned lots of good thoughts but I'll add a bit.  Even staying away from ancient history and sticking to recent years, in addition to clickers (I don't know the vendor they want me to use here), people have been telling me that I should record my classes on video (we have Tegrity), digitize all my whiteboard work (we have SmartBoard), flip my classroom (I think they want me to use Kahn Academy), or fold in MOOC's (there seems to be interest in EdX) or Open Educational Resources (the one at Carnegie Mellon is often mentioned), and use a learning management systems (we have recently switched to Canvas, so things built in the prior one may well be lost).

No one wants to be *that guy*.  But aren't you skeptical?

Here are two specific things that are in my cloud of help-make-me-skeptical thoughts. (1) These things are all a ratcheting-up, that all add degrees of franticness to the class and therefore threaten a focus on the work at hand.  (2) Going back to ancient history, the best guide to success for typical students has been to come to class and to do the homework.  Perhaps new stuff is a big win, and faculty that are interested should definitely experiment (I've tried some things on the above list; for example last semester I flipped a Business Calc class), but I often take a pass myself.

Comment: First of all, I like the idea of short reinforcing videos, but all this is placing a huge burden on the teacher. After 10 years, I should be able to pull this stuff off the net and curate it rather than build from scratch.  But that's just theory, even if I can find materials that pass my 98% of everything is crap filter.  Right now, this means a huge investment.  Having said that, I think you should look into CLOZE questions. CLOZE is a reasonable standard, so even if they switch from Canvas to moodle/next flavor, you can keep your question set.  CLOZE embedded questions are awesome

Comment: I wonder what you are talking about?  Possibly you meant to reply to a different post?

Comment: check out using a learning management systems with web-based questions as opposed to videos.  Both require effort, but videos are a lot more effort, and questions can port around better.  With a video you still need questions to see who watched, how much they retained.  I am finding (for computer science at least) that asking targeted questions strongly reinforces the learning by forcing students to focus on the specific questions I want them to consider.

Answer (score 6):

I originally wrote that there is independent data showing no difference in outcomes.

This was based on a presentation at Stevens Institute of Technology where they tested clickers and found that students were more enthusiastic in class, and that attendence rose.
At the time, they said that scores did not rise.  Scores after all, are the objective goal.  If students don't understand any better, then the immediate goals are more ego-gratification for the professor.

Today, 10 years later, the professor says they use clickers, and find that they still achieve the immediate improvements.  He cannot tell me about grades because they don't do any studies on it.  It is hard to believe that grades cannot improve based on better attendance, but without objective measurement, I still believe their initial impressions which were based on comparison of year on year scores.  Another way of looking at this is that as the studies by the ASU modeling curriculum found, students of physics don't believe what they are writing.  When asked what happens in a "real" situation they give Aristotelian answers.  In other words, the lecturer can improve lecture mechanics with clickers, but unless they change the way they teach, the fundamental scores won't change because the students don't really believe the physics.  Anyway, sorry, but that's peculiar to physics.

I teach programming, and I find that multiple choice questions are of limited utility. I can sometimes ask the right question.  But the best test of computer programming ability (aside from asking for an entire program) is to see whether people know what to type in a particular place without prompting.  This is short answer, and complicated short answer since multiple answers can sometimes be acceptable.  I will attach some sample questions I ask below.[image: Example of CLOZE questions]

Personally, using clickers takes time, and I have moodle and can tell them to review things at home and answer my questions there.  That way, I get them to study out of class, review what we did, and it reinforces it without taking up classtime.  I find that works better for me, but in any case I am teaching graduate classes, without access to uniform clickers.

Comment: Do you have a link or reference to the data you mention in the first paragraph?

Comment: No, but I know it was a study of physics students in freshman year.  I will ask the guy who presented and get back to you.  The upshot was there was initially more interaction, which seemed net positive, but there was zero impact on scores which was their metric.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft this study, although not only about clickers, says it works http://www.sciencemag.org/content/332/6031/862.short

Comment: Checked back with the professor who presented.  Clickers there appear to work as well.  At least, he discusses enthusiasm and class participation which you have to believe would have an impact.

Answer (score 6):

A colleague of mine recently tried out a very cheap low-tech alternative: university students were provided with red and green pieces of cardboard, to be folded by the students themselves. They were asked to place these on their desk, one hidden inside the other, and could thus very visually indicate their answer to the basic question “do you understand”. The results were quite good, so I think I might adapt that approach when next I'm facing a larger audience.

Comment: Greetings MvG and welcome to ME:SE!

Comment: A colleague of mine used to use clickers but then switched to a system like that mentioned above: she gave the students pieces of paper with A, B, C and D printed on them large enough to fill the page, and she asked them to hold up the appropriate sheet in response to occasional multiple choice questions.  I might try that next time I teach a large class.

Comment: I sometimes ask my students to shake their heads up and down if they understand, side to side if they don't, or shrug their shoulders if they're middling. No technology, No hassle, No cost, always works.

Answer (score 5):

I don't use clickers nor anything like that because I teach on the assumption that each person seated in front of me is an adult, in charge of their own learning. Of course that is not true in many cases these days, but to me the fact that university students want to behave like children is still no reason to treat them as such.

Because of the above, and since the students have already lots of means to communicate with me (personally before, during, and after class; office hours; email) plus other resources (the course web page, their notes, the textbook, tutoring, online searches), I find no use for clickers in my class.

Comment: Exactly. You know, there is another side to all of this. What if clickers work? What if we feed the students like little baby birds and they do learn more? If it all works, and they learn more content then what? We have created a class of creatures who cannot think for themselves unless someone entertains them. We should be creating challenges for them to overcome with the (if this still makes sense) "old college try". That ought to mean something!

Comment: "We have created a class of creatures who cannot think for themselves". That's only true if you use the clickers in a way that doesn't reward thinking. Nobody here has mentioned a very common method used with clickers: you ask the question, don't display the results, and then ask everyone to discuss their answers with people around them and respond again. Frequently the class converges on the correct answer with no instructor help. In this case, _someone_ must be thinking for themselves; contrast that with a lecture in which it often seems no one is doing any thinking at all.

Comment: @Dan: of course someone is thinking by himself or herself. But I don't see how getting the whole class to ask a question to the thinking minority helps at all.

Answer (score 5):

I really liked using clickers myself. Ultimately (and this was about 8 years ago) I only had two classes that used them for attendance and a daily quiz. Physics. The problem with them was that they were somewhat expensive, didn't always work, and if you forgot yours you were SOL for that lecture's participation points. The one thing that stood out in my mind was that between the two physics classes we had to have two different clickers. They had changed the type of clicker used between the two classes even though they were parts 1 and 2.

I imagine if clickers were used more often they would require at lease some uniformity between departments and from the school's purchasing. I personally really did think they were a great idea. Perfect for instant feedback from students.